# Promoting a pawn

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion

When a pawn reaches the opposing side it can be promoted. Given that the most advantageous choice of promotion is to a Queen I have 3 questions.

1. Does this mean that the newly promoted piece (e.g. Queen) stays on the opposing side and can attack from the rear?
2. Does this mean (hypothetically) that there can be 3 Queens on the board?
3. How does one represent the newly promoted Queen if there are still 2 on the board?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it is in all facets equal to an original queen of the same color as the pawn.
2. Yes, in fact this happens quite often, even among grandmaster. There are even cases known where there were [6 queens](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/recordstxt.htm#Most%20queens) on the board!
3. In official games, you'll need a queen from another chess set. In casual games, you could put a rook upside down. Don't do this in tournament games - the piece will be considered to be a rook. If there's no queen available, stop the clock and call the arbiter.

Comment: Some chess sets come with a spare queen of each color, to make this easier.  That doesn't help if you need more, of course...

Comment: I am curious about this : Is it possible for the pawn to under promote to a own itself that can go in the reverse direction from which it came ? For example, can a white pawn promote to a pawn hat can now move in the direction the black pawn originally could.

Comment: @user230452 no, according to the official rules this is not possible. At this moment, I can't resist to share a link to [this beautiful endgame study](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess/gukal.html) where a pawn 'sort of' goes in reverse.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for sharing. I'm new to this. I understood the first case how white could win if the pawn could move backwards. I also understood the last paragraph where white could win if that pawn was replaced by a queen. But, can you explain how he replaced that pawn by a queen ? Or was it two different endgames ?

Comment: @user230452 IMHO, White performed a manoeuver to first promote the pawn to a queen, and then moved that queen back to the original position, thus achieving the effect of replacing the pawn by the queen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it will behave just like any other queen.
2. There can be up to 9 queens on each side -- one for each potential pawn promotion and 1 original one.
3. Just find a queen of the same colour from a different set.